# If $\mu(e_1,...e_n)=1$, then how to show that $\mu=f^1\wedge f^2...\wedge f^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

Let V be a n dimensional vector space, $\mu$ be an antisymmetric n tensor.(i.e, a real valued multilinear functional with n inputs) If there exists a basis for $V$, say, {$e_1,e_2,...,e_n$}, such that $\mu(e_1,...e_n)=1$,with corresponding dual basis $f_1,...f_n$ then how to show that $\mu=f^1\wedge f^2...\wedge f^n$?

Comment: Considering the notation $\wedge$, is $\mu$ assumed to be symmetric or something? Otherwise, I do not think the result is true.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi See my new edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to a constant, there is only one such tensor, i.e. you know

$$
\mu=C f^1\wedge f^2...\wedge f^n
$$

and just need to determine that $C = 1$; evaluating on the basis does precisely this.